How do I make my 2d orbit animation in matplotlib smoother?
I am trying to animate a 2D circular orbit around the origin. I got the below code working but the trailing line "blinks" everytime it crosses the positive x-axis (completes a full rotation). I understand that this happens when I re-set the data inside the animate function, but I have no idea how to fix this. Is it possible to implement smoothly?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax.set_xlim(-20, 20)
ax.set_ylim(-20, 20)
ax.axhline(0, color='black', linewidth=0.5)
ax.axvline(0, color='black', linewidth=0.5)

rads = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
x = 5*np.cos(rads)
y = 5*np.sin(rads)
point, = ax.plot(5, 0, color='red', marker="o")
line, = ax.plot([], [], color='red')

def animate(i):
    speed = 1000
    # arg - used in resetting the orbit 
    arg = (i - (2*np.pi*int(i/((2*np.pi)*(100/speed))))*(100/speed))*speed
    line.set_data(x[int(arg):int(arg)+50], y[int(arg):int(arg)+50])
    point.set_data([5*np.cos(i*(speed/100)-100)],[5*np.sin(i*(speed/100)-100)])
    return line, point,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, frames=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,int(2*np.pi/0.01), endpoint=False),interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()


After several trials, I surprisedly find that you just need to add a variable named circle(default=2) to control the trailing line running distance, and if you increase the value the trailing line will run a longer time, which means it will conquer your problem temporarily.
circle = 4  # The larger, the longer time trailing line will remain unchanged

and then change the corresponding line in your code:
rads = np.arange(0, circle*np.pi, 0.01)
...
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
      fig, animate, frames=np.linspace(0,circle*np.pi,int(circle*np.pi/0.01), endpoint=False),interval=20, blit=True)

The trial is derived from a thought: though the problem happens while resetting the data inside the animate function, we can extend the data length until the trailing line running with sufficient time.
However I still have no idea why this operation would work in details.

Wow. That was so simple. Thank you!
